# Difference between "deny doing something" and "deny having done something"

Tags: meaning, differences, present-perfect, progressive-aspect, legalese

What is the difference between "deny doing something" and "deny having done something"?

The context is as follows:

> While being questioned on the court, the man denied [taking/having taken] the old lady's necklace.

Which one is correct, or are both? Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: Either are grammatical. Personally I prefer 'having taken'in speech as it always seems to me less likely to be mis-heard or misunderstood. But I am wondering what you mean by 'on the court'? Clearly if you are talking about a tennis-court, 'on' is correct, but if it is a court of law, it would need to be be 'questioned by the court', or 'in court'.

Comment: @WC2 Rather, *both **are** grammatical* or *either **is** grammatical*, insofar as either **aren’t** grammatical. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use of *have* as auxiliary emphasizes that an action is completed. Though both forms are going to be properly understood in context, you would generally use the *have* version when dealing with an action that started and finished at an identifiable point in the past.

As I see it, the following are to be preferred w/o *have*, since they refer to activities which are either ongoing or intermittent:

> Thomas denied taking the metro to work on Wednesdays.
>  Thomas denied
>   being a stamp collector.

On the other hand (as most typically occurs with allegations of criminal acts), if the event has a definite starting and end point, then the *have* version is preferred:

> Thomas denied having taken the metro on Wednesday January 8th
>   Thomas denied having purchased the Three Dragons stamp.

Comment: Good point, but perhaps you could work on the examples. I could certainly *deny being a stamp collector* since I have no stamp albums. But to convincingly *deny having been a stamp collector* would require me to bring evidence from those who knew me as a boy.

Comment: @TimLymington yes, because when you say *deny having been...* you imply that there was a definite point in the past at which you stopped being a stamp collector. saying *deny being...* is interpreted to mean that there is an ongoing identification. what is wrong with my examples?

Comment: *The man admitted taking the necklace* is as much a reference to a specific point in time as *The man admitted having taken the necklace*.  It is, however, at least as idiomatic, which seems to be what OP is asking about. If you are merely saying the latter is better than the former, I misunderstood (and I disagree with you). I thought there was something more subtle there, about denying altering the 'point in the past' concept.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think both are acceptable, but 'doing something' sounds much more natual to me,
 because I don't feel the necessary to use 'having done something' form.
If 'having taken' were required in that sentence to mean the taking occurred in the past,
 then other similar verbs like 'remember', 'forget' and the like
would have to need 'having done something' to express 'the doing' happened before.
      **I remember you saying that Nathan was such a bother.

      (I remember that you said Nathan was such a bother.)**
Simple use of the gerund form 'saying' is good enough
to understand that **'your saying was in the past.'**
So my take is there would be no difference between them,
and I might use 'having taken' for writing in a formal way if I had to use that form.